# Squash for already pushed commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase, squash, git-squash

I am trying to squash 9 commits of my  branch, and for this, I ran this command:

> git rebase -i HEAD~9

After then, it showed editor on terminal. Then, I edited the first one as **pick** , and rest one as squash. Then, to save it, I ran

> Ctrl+X+S

- Then, it saved but didn't showed any message.
- I ran

> git rebase --continue

- Then, a number of conflicts came based on each commit. And resolved them manually and keep on doing :

> git add .

- After resolving all, it asked to edit commit message. Then , I edited the message and saved it using : Ctrl+X+S
- And then, I ran

> git log --oneline

But all of that rebased commit and normal commits are getting shown.

So, am I doing something wrong ? I don't know where I am doing wrong. I need to squash. Please suggest.

Comment: I took pull from my branch <A> and want to squash commits and want to push forcefully back to <A>. So that it should seem only one commit. Is it possible ?